# Probabilities in a Pick 3 lottery

Tags: probability

In a Pick 3 lottery three numbers are drawn from three separate sets of numbers, between 0 and 9.
Matching 2 winning numbers, one of them duplicated, can be done in 3 ways, according to all lotteries websites.
But I found 18 ways to do it.
As an example:
If the winning numbers are 1 2 3, then there are 18 possible ways to win:

```
1   1   2
1   1   3
1   2   1
1   2   2
1   3   1
1   3   3
2   1   1
2   1   2
2   2   1
2   2   3
2   3   2
2   3   3
3   1   1
3   1   3
3   2   2
3   2   3
3   3   1
3   3   2
```

Since the probability is equal to the number of favourable outcomes divided by the number of possible outcomes, it will be 18 divided by 1,000. The odds would be 1 in 55.55

Please let me know if I am making a mistake in my calculations.